# How to lay limits to the entry in text fields?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm having 4 textfields in my application

1.username 2.Email 3.Age 4.Password

User names are 3-25 characters and contain only the characters [a-z0-9]

Age must be between 1-100 inclusive.

Passwords are between 4-12 characters and use only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9]

how can i restrict the textfield with above requirements

please anyone help me out to do this..

Thank you for your effort and consideration.

Comment: check all limits in shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. In particular, those things you want can be programmed in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

For the minimum length, you can use `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`

For example, to check the length of the user name:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == _userNameTextField && [[textField text] length] - range.length + [string length] > 25) {
        return NO;
    }
    // add any other check here
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == _userNameTextField && [[textField text] length] < 3) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: [[textField text] length] - range.length + [string length]. Sir,what is the meaning of this code ? What is range.length,[textfield.text length] & [string length]?

Comment: Sir,and can i validate email address in the above functiin and if so can you please give the coding & explain a bit because i am a bit confused in the use of NSRegular & NSPredicate? I would be very much thankful if you solve this problem of mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)emailStr {
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailStr];
```

}

Then, you can display an alert if email address is wrong:

```
- (void)checkEmailAndDisplayAlert {
if(![self validateEmail:[aTextField text]]) {
    // user entered invalid email address
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Enter a valid email address." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} else {
    // user entered valid email address
}
```

}

For Password:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
//delete
if (string.length == 0) {
    return YES;
}

if (self.regEx) {
    NSMutableString* check = [NSMutableString stringWithString:theTextField.text];
    [check replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSTextCheckingResult* match = [self.regEx firstMatchInString:check options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [check length])];
    if (match.range.length != check.length) {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For Every textfield you need validation
Here i Give you example

**(1)For Username 
Validation :**

- (BOOL) isAlphaNumeric:(NSString *) candidate

{

```
if (![self isEmpty:candidate])
{
    NSString *alphaNumberRegex = @"^\\s*([A-Z0-9a-z ]*)\\s*$"; 
    NSPredicate *alphaNumberTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", alphaNumberRegex]; 

    return [alphaNumberTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
return NO;
```

}

**(2)For Email Validation**
+ (BOOL) isValidEmailAddress:(NSString *) candidate
{

```
if (![self isEmpty:candidate])
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
return NO;
```

}

**(3) For Age Validation**

Apple provide numeric keyboard.So for age you can use this keyboard which contain only numeric value

**(4) For Password Validation**

- (BOOL) isPasswordValid:(NSString *)pwd
  {

  if ( [pwd length] < 8 || [pwd length]> 100 )

  ```
  return NO;
  ```

  if (![self isEmpty:pwd])
  {
      NSString *alphaNumberRegex = @"^\s*([A-Z0-9a-z ]*)\s*$";

  ```
  NSPredicate *alphaNumberTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", alphaNumberRegex];

  return [alphaNumberTest evaluateWithObject:pwd];
  ```

  }
  return NO;
  }

Comment: The function you have declared like isPasswordvalid are user defined or r there any predefined functions like this?